# How can reduce the number of URL rewriting configs in Django

Tags: django, url, django-generic-views

I have this listing in django. These looks identical. Is there any way to make one line from these four lines

```
(r'^book/list/$', list_detail.object_list, book_info),
(r'^author/list/$', list_detail.object_list, author_info),
(r'^publisher/list/$', list_detail.object_list, publisher_info),
(r'^shop/list/$', list_detail.object_list, shop_info),
```

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer to leave it like it is so you can clearly see the urls of your site (and each list can have a name for use with {% url %}, but perhaps you can do something like:

```
(r'^(?P<model>\w+)/list/$', list_detail.object_list)
```

Then in the views.py:

```
def object_list(request, model):
    if model == 'books':
        return books_list(request)

def books_list(request):
    # whatever
```

I think what you have is best though.

Comment: +1. If you want to have lesser number of entries, you just need to have lesser number of patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your terms in the regular expression, using an OR character which is designed by the pipe symbol.  Something like this:
(r'^(book|author|publisher|shop)/list/$', list_detail.object_list, shop_info),

I'm presuming that you don't want to use a wildcard character.

Comment: but i have diff function as well shop_info , book_info . they are models